# Are these two estimated regression coefficient asymptotically equivalent? If not, which one is more efficient?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, efficiency, two-step-estimation, semiparametric

Suppose I have $Y=\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_1X_2+g(X_2)+u$, where $E(u|X_1,X_2)=0$ and $S=g(X_2)+e$ with $E(e|X_2)=0$. I have a random sample $\{Y_i,X_{1i},X_{2i},S_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Suppose I first use a nonparametric method such as kernel or series regression to fit $\widehat{g}(X_2)$, and then consider the following two estimators of $\beta_1,\beta_2$:

1. Since $Y-g(X_2)=\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_1X_2+u$, I can regress $Y-\widehat{g}(X_2)$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$ and obtain my estimator 1 for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$.
2. Since $Y-E(Y|X_2)=\beta_1(X_1-E(X_1|X_2))+\beta_2(X_1-E(X_1|X_2))X_2$, I can regress $Y-\widehat{g}(X_2)$ on $X_1-\widehat{E}(X_1|X_2)$ and $(X_1-\widehat{E}(X_1|X_2))X_2$ and obtain my estimator 2 for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$, where $\widehat{E}(X_1|X_2)$ also uses a nonparametric fit.

My question is are estimator 1 and estimator 2 asymptotically equivalent? If not, which one is more efficient and why?

My guess is that they are not asymptotically equivalent for two reasons. First, they involve different estimated unknown functions using nonparametric methods. Second, with some abuse of notation suppose let $X$ be the 2 by 1 vector of regressors in both regressions, then these two regressions require different rank conditions ($E(XX')$ being invertible).

Does this look correct?
Also I got no clue on which one is more efficient, and which one is preffered in practice.

Comment: Your problem setup doesn't exclude heteroscedasticity, but I'm assuming you mean errors are iid.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to draw any conclusions based on vague characterizations of the estimators as being "nonparametric."  I think we would need to know more specifically how you are making these intermediate estimates.